# A random seed that makes tests fail the same way every time?

Tags: python, algorithm, testing, random, random-seed

I've never worked with the random library and I'm a bit confused about what this fixme statement is asking me to do. Is there a seed number that specifically does this?

The code is making an ordered list ADT and this file is testing the functions within that file. We use the random library to create random numbers that will be added into, or removed from the ordered list ADT.

Please let me know if there's any other information I should give!

[image]

[image]

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: It is `fix`, not `fixme`. `seed()` always with the same value will always gives the same random values - and it is method (fix) to easier compare it with previous test because you see the same random values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `seed`, as is done here, you should get a consistent set of random numbers afterwards.

If the numbers that you're getting are NOT consistent, then one of the following is true:

1. You're using a different random number function somewhere so setting the seed didn't fix it.
2. The test depends on external state, so it does different things on different runs.
3. You're trying to compare running the entire test suite to testing a single function.

The right fix will depend on which of those is the issue.

1. Find where you're using a different generator and either stop, or mock it out.
2. Find the external state and set it or mock it out.
3. Move setting the seed into a `setUp` method so that it is set fresh for every test.

My guess is that your problem is the last.  But if it isn't, hopefully this answer gives you somewhere to start digging from.

Answer (score 1):

The random library will generate the same sequence of random numbers (!) when you provide the same seed value. Any seed will do - `652` is fine as in your example - but could be `7`, or `42`, or any `int` value. This is counter-intuitive but basic random numbers generated like this are more accurately called `pseudo-random numbers` - they are not 100% random since the random sequence can be regenerated exactly the same. This is good for testing though, as indicated in your question.

For this parameter we have the following notes from the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

`random.seed(a=None)`

- Initialize the random number generator.
- If `a` is omitted or `None`, the current system time is used. If
  randomness sources are provided by the operating system, they are
  used instead of the system time.
- If `a` is an `int`, it is used directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you fix a number using the `seed` method, all calls for a pseudo-random methods will return the same numbers associated to order of the calls. If you change the number you will have different succession of random numbers. That's why if you want that the random calls produce a different or not controlled value set the seed with a hard to predict number like the exact current time.